# CSS to align image and text

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to create 3 buttons like that :

[exepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxDmf.jpg)

This is the result I have on Google Chrome browser on Android :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aus8N.jpg)

How can I align my text and images ? This is my source code. What properties should I use to have a proper alignment with my elements ? I am sorry for my dummie question but I never develop front web site and I am confronted to it.

```css
body{
  display: block !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#message_bienvenue{
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#bouton_mission{
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#livraison_chauffeur{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

.container-fluid{
  margin-top: 70px !important;
}

.navbar-nastasi{
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

/* BOUTON */
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.btn-circle.btn-small {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 45px;
  font-size: 34px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px
}

.text-button{
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.text-button label{
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <link rel="icon" href="">
 <title>Title</title>
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 120px !important">
  <form method="post" action="requetes/creerMission.php" role="form" id="formulaire">
  <h1>Title :</h1>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="item_id" type="number" name="item_id" placeholder="Numéro de bon de livraison" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" placeholder="Client" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="item_desc" name="item_desc" type="text" placeholder="Adresse" required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="number_items" type="number" name="number_items" placeholder="M³" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" formnovalidate required>
  <hr/>
  <input class="form-control" id="item_brand"type="text" name="item_brand" placeholder="Centrale" required>
  <hr/>
  <span class="label label-default">Type</span>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="idtype" type="text" name="idtype">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
   <option>11</option>
   <option>12</option>
   <option>13</option>
   <option>14</option>
   <option>15</option>
   <option>16</option>
   <option>17</option>
   <option>18</option>
   <option>19</option>
   <option>20</option>
  </select>
  <hr/>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 0 !important">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
     <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small" id="id_validate" name="myvalue" value="Value1" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" width="40"/>
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn-circle btn-xl" id="id_validate_annulee" name="myvalue" value="Value2" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" width="40"/>
     </button>
     <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small" id="id_validate_replacee" name="myvalue" value="Value3" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" width="40"/>
     </button>
   </div>
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around text-button">
     <label>My image 1</label>
     <label>My image 2</label>
     <label>My image 3</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
body {
  display: block !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#message_bienvenue {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#bouton_mission {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#livraison_chauffeur {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 90%;
}

.container-fluid {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.navbar-nastasi {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
}

#MainFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* BOUTON */

.btn-xl img {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

.text-button {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.text-button label {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 120px;">
    <form method="post" action="requetes/creerMission.php" role="form" id="formulaire">
      <h1>Title :</h1>
      <hr/>
      <input class="form-control" id="item_id" type="number" name="item_id" placeholder="Numéro de bon de livraison" required>
      <hr/>
      <input class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" placeholder="Client" required>
      <hr/>
      <input class="form-control" id="item_desc" name="item_desc" type="text" placeholder="Adresse" required>
      <hr/>
      <input class="form-control" id="number_items" type="number" name="number_items" placeholder="M³" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" formnovalidate required>
      <hr/>
      <input class="form-control" id="item_brand" type="text" name="item_brand" placeholder="Centrale" required>
      <hr/>
      <span class="label label-default">Type</span>
      <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="idtype" type="text" name="idtype">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
      </select>
      <hr/>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex" id="MainFlex">
          <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small" id="id_validate" name="myvalue" value="Value1" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" width="40"/>
     </button>
          <button class="btn btn-circle btn-xl" id="id_validate_annulee" name="myvalue" value="Value2" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" />
     </button>
          <button class="btn btn-circle btn-small" id="id_validate_replacee" name="myvalue" value="Value3" type="submit">
      <img src="https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6631150_preview.png" width="40"/>
     </button>
        </div>


        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around text-button">
          <label>My image 1</label>
          <label>My image 2</label>
          <label>My image 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I tried your code and it seems it doesn't produce the excepted result.

Comment: You want the small buttons to be aligned with the big one right?

Comment: @HarverR I have updated my code, I also removed some code which was not needed to those buttons. I have added a color(Red) to make sure it is aligned center, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try "vertical-align:middle;" on the parent element, or manually adjust the bottom margin of the smaller buttons to fit them into place.